# Android spinner divider line

Tags: spinner, divide, divider

How can i add a divider after a spinner like the divider between user name and password
[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to add a *horizontal line.*

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```